# Does twice the cpu benchmark score mean it can get a job twice as fast?

Tags: processor

Does twice the cpu benchmark score mean it can get a job twice as fast?
Let’s say I bought a cpu that has twice the single thread performance score of what I used to have. Does this mean it can complete a job twice as fast? Assume the program I’m using is not multi threaded. By single thread performance score I mean numbers on websites like this https://www.cpubenchmark.net/singleThread.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the benchmark. If you use something like Blender as a benchmark, sure, but not all benchmarks are the same at calculating the score. Blender uses time elapsed and that is in my opinion the best way.

Comment: Thanks, your answer scared me quite a bit because I wasn’t sure how you could tell that I use blender xd

Comment: the time it takes to render a blender render is a way to benchmark.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it could mean that unless the increased processing causes other resource contentions.

For example if you run out of RAM your speed will drop.

If it accesses the hard drive a lot, and you only have a standard motorized hard drive instead of an SSD or NVMe you *could* easily have a bottleneck here.

If it downloads data from the network or internet that could become a new bottleneck.